# Can we observe the 24-hour cycle distribution of when votes are cast?

Tags: discussion, voting, statistics, data-explorer

Is there a way to view a distribution of numbers of votes cast (for questions or for answers) over the 24-hour daily cycle? Or over a full weekly cycle? I didn't find such a query at data.SE.

Comment: Voting time stamp is sanitized from the data dumps, since it is possible to reconstruct voting pattern and find who voted what.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can't observe this directly, but we can group posts by the hour of the day in which they were posted and compute the average scores of each group. I wrote a query for this [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/revision/269434/352007/post-score-by-hour#graph). From the graph, it shows that the most activity happens near midnight UTC (or whatever $0$ is), with posts averaging a score of $2.45$ and the least happens near 9:00 UTC, with an average post score of $2.18$ - so there's about a $12\%$ difference in the average scores. There is a similar query by someone else [here](http://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/1718/up-vs-down-votes-by-day-of-week-of-question-or-answer) which produces separate results for answers and questions by day of week.